# How to use XSL to make a href using XML data

Tags: nginx, directory, web, xml

I'm trying to create an XML file that shows different news articles within an iframe. A shortened version of the news' body is shown as a subtitle (which is already prewritten and chosen with the help of PHP, this isn't the issue) and to show the full body, the idea is to take the user to a link where the full body is shown. The PHP creates a file in the folder 'articles' on the root directory which contains the full body with the folder name as the title (e.g if the title was 'foo' then the xml file would be under: /articles/foo/index.xml (the XSL is already done for that file)).

My idea is to add a link to the XML with the shortened body to the XML page that would link to the file in the articles folder to allow a user to read the whole body. How would I, using the XSL stylesheet, create a link to this XML page with the whole body?

Below is the code for the XML and XSL to be used in the iframe (without the body)

XML code:

```
...
<articles>
<article>
<title>(This is what I want to be used as a link)</title>
<image></image>
<subtitle></subtitle>
</article>
</articles>
```

XSL code:

```
...
<table...>
    <xsl:for-each select="articles/article">
    <th...><img src="{image}"...></th>
    <th...><h1><xsl:value-of select="title" /></h1></th>
    </xsl:for-each>
</tr>
<tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="articles/article">
    <th...><h2><xsl:value-of select="subtitle" /></h2></th>
    </xsl:for-each>
</tr>
</table>
...
```

I'm looking to set the XSL title part to a href to link to the mentioned page. How would I do this?

Comment: In other words, I need to append a "<a href=articles/(title)>" to the <xsl:value-of select="title" />

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out by, in the XSL, doing the following:

```
...
<th...><h1><a href="articles/{title}/index.xml"><xsl:value-of select="title" /></a></h1></th>
...
```